# how to deal with viruses in windowsXP?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

A very bad virus has struck my P.C. I am not able to open my control panel or add and remove programs in my P.C.
Even if i type antivirus in my Mozilla browser ,it shuts down. How am I supposed to download any antivirus to scan the the viruses? and other browsers dont work. I tried downloading again,but they still don't work.

Answer (score 1):

When your windows is booting, press "F8", it will ask for some options to load windows on diferent ways, just choose the "Safe-mode" option. When your windows boot-up, if you dont have an anti-virus, install one and pass a complete scanning. This way your anti-virus will remove any problems that it detects. (Dont forget to update your antivirus's virus database.)